# Entity Framework Filling IEnurable(Of Cars) --- How do I fill

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity, poco

Fellow Coders, How do I use the entity framework to fill a POCO?  In other words I have coded out a Class Called Car with lets say 3 properties

```
Public Class Car
Private _car_id As Int32
Private _car_make As String
Private _car_model As String


Public Sub New(ByVal car_id As Int32, _
               ByVal car_make As String, _
               ByVal car_model As String)
End Sub


Public Property Car_id As Int32
    Get
        Return _car_id
    End Get
    Set(value As Int32)
        _car_id = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Car_Make As String
    Get
        Return _Car_Make
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _car_make = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Car_Model As String
    Get
        Return _car_model
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _car_model = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Now I need to populate an IEnumerable to keep a list of my Car Objects for future use and I will need to perform a cross compare on another Entity Call in my code.

```
Public Function GetCars() As IEnumerable(Of CarDB)

Dim data As New List(Of CarDB)

Using ctx As New FundingEntities()

    Dim query = From x In ctx.tbl_cars
    Select New ???????????
```

This is where I get lost...  How do I fill my IEnumberabl(Of CarDB)????

Any good POCO and Entity Coders please lend a hand, so I can get over this hump...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be more LINQ related.  As long as tbl_cars contains all three fields that you intend to store in a "Car" object, you can do the following:

```
Dim query As IEnumerable(Of Car) = From x In ctx.tbl_cars Select New Car With {.Car_id = x.Id, .Car_make = x.Make, .Car_Model = x.Model}
```

Comment: Question are we missing a "Select" in the From x in ctx.tblcars

Comment: If so I am getting an error on Key --- Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer mus start with '.'   We are very close I believe.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: I am reading the following which is helping me out - http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/bb385125(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx

Comment: Object Initializers: Named and Anonymous Types (Visual Basic)

Comment: The problem may be in the converter that I'm using from C# to vb.net.  In C# it should look like the following: IEnumerable<CarDB> query = from x in ctx.tbl select new CarDB() { Car_id = x.Id, Car_Make = x.Make, Car_Model = x.Model };

Comment: Yes, I do agree I am stuck in VB.NET ---  But pays the bills.

Comment: I am not liking this .Car_id notation and not sure if I need the Key word.

Comment: Updated what you see above.  The converter that I had used was missing the Select (as you had stated).  Also, it appears that "Key" was not needed.